# How can I use data received as response from google api?

Tags: go

I'm trying to create login with google api authentication with oauth2.
I'm getting response from google api (response.body) as:

```
{
 "id": "received ID",
 "email": "EMAIL",
 "verified_email": true,
 "name": "Name",
}
```

How can I access that data inside go program so that I can store it in database?

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "io/ioutil"
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "net/url"
    "strings"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
    "encoding/json"
)

var (
    oauthConf = &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     "CLIENTID",
        ClientSecret: "Secret",
        RedirectURL:  "http://localhost:8011/showprofile",
        //Scopes:       []string{"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.login"},
        Scopes:[]string{"profile","email"},
        Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
    }
    oauthStateString = "thisshouldberandom"
)

const htmlIndex = `<html><body>
Logged in with <a href="/login">facebook</a>
</body></html>
`

func handleMain(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")
    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
    w.Write([]byte(htmlIndex))
}

func handleGoogleLogin(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    Url, err := url.Parse(oauthConf.Endpoint.AuthURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal("Parse: ", err)
    }
    parameters := url.Values{}
    parameters.Add("client_id", oauthConf.ClientID)
    parameters.Add("scope", strings.Join(oauthConf.Scopes, " "))
    parameters.Add("redirect_uri", oauthConf.RedirectURL)
    parameters.Add("response_type", "code")
    parameters.Add("state", oauthStateString)
    Url.RawQuery = parameters.Encode()
    url := Url.String()
    fmt.Println("URL" + url)
    http.Redirect(w, r, url, http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func handleGoogleCallback(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    fmt.Println("Call back working")
    state := r.FormValue("state")
    if state != oauthStateString {
        fmt.Printf("invalid oauth state, expected '%s', got '%s'\n", oauthStateString, state)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }

    code := r.FormValue("code")

    token, err := oauthConf.Exchange(oauth2.NoContext, code)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("oauthConf.Exchange() failed with '%s'\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }


    resp,err:=  http.Get("https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v2/userinfo?access_token=" + token.AccessToken)

    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("Get: %s\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println(resp.Body)
    defer resp.Body.Close()

    response, err := ioutil.ReadAll(resp.Body)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Printf("ReadAll: %s\n", err)
        http.Redirect(w, r, "/showprofile", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
        return
    }



    log.Printf("parseResponseBody: %s\n", string(response))

    http.Redirect(w, r, "/showprofile", http.StatusTemporaryRedirect)
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handleMain)
    http.HandleFunc("/login", handleGoogleLogin)
    http.HandleFunc("/showprofile", handleGoogleCallback)
    fmt.Print("Started running on http://localhost:8011\n")
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8011", nil))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed it by using json.Unmarshal.